# i keep running into problems with if elif and else in c++

Tags: c++

question: every time I run the program and I input who are you it says Error Value of a is not matching what is going on? (yes I am a noob to c++)
code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

   // local variable declaration:
   string a;
   cin >> a;
   // check the boolean condition
   if( a == "hello" ) {
      // if condition is true then print the following
      cout << "hi" << endl;
   } else if( a == "who are you" ) {
      // if else if condition is true
      cout << "a better question is who are you?" << endl;
   } else if( a == "what am i doing" ) {
      // if else if condition is true
      cout << "reading this output  " << endl;
   }else {
      // if none of the conditions is true
      cout << "Error Value of a is not matching" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> a` will only read one word. How can it be equal to `"who are you"`?

Comment: Read the string using std::getline()

Comment: If you tried printing `a` you would have seen the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator >> for streams and strings inputs words separated by white spaces. You should use a function that can read at once several words up to the Enter key will be pressed. For example you can use standard function `std::getline`

Also you need to include header `<string>`.

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;

    if ( std::getline( std::cin, s ) )
    {
        // check the boolean condition
        if ( s == "hello" ) 
        {
            // if condition is true then print the following
            std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
        } 
        else if ( s == "who are you" ) 
        {
            // if else if condition is true
            std::cout << "a better question is who are you?" << std::endl;
        } 
        else if ( s == "what am i doing" ) 
        {
            // if else if condition is true
            std::cout << "reading this output  " << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            // if none of the conditions is true
            std::cout << "Error Value of a is not matching" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```